# Is form target="_self" is vulnerable?

Tags: php, forms, security, target

I have a confusion, i was going through a blog and in its comment it was suggested that  target="_self" is vulnerable. It is true, if yes how we can fix it?

```
<form action="../process.php" method="post" name="login-form" target="_self">
    <div class="FormItem">Username:
      <span id="sprytextfield1">
      <input class="textbox" type="text" name="text1" id="text1">
      <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>
      </div>

      <div class="clear"></div>

      <div class="FormItem">Password:
        <span id="sprypassword1">
        <input class="textbox" type="password" name="password" id="password1">
      <span class="passwordRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>
      </div>

      <div class="FormItem">
      <input name="login-submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Define "vulnerable" in this context.

Comment: Vulnerable: "Exposed to the possibility of being attacked or harmed"

I need to know whether it has anything to do with php secure form processing.. or it has nothing to do with it?

Comment: @cHao I think if somebody needs help we should do that :)

Comment: I *really, really* have to know who said that, since "_self" is the default target...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Man was browsing on mobile yesterday found some article naming php alarm or something...

Comment: Tell the author he's an idiot.  Or give me his name, so i can tell him.

Comment: @cHao dude will obviously do the needful... anyways the author did not commented, he had a decent article... some anonymous has commented... so chill - thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it has nothing to do with security

the last time i used target, it was just to tell the form where the results are to be displayed, be it in the page itself, an iframe, or another frame in a frameset. as far as i know, it's pretty much useless.

[here's a reference from sitepoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/form/target), indicating that "target" in forms are deprecated. (Hint: they died with Frameset)

> The target attribute is deprecated, and, like the use of frameset for layout purposes, it’s no longer widely used. However, if you do find yourself having to maintain a frameset-based web site, you may wish to present the results of a form submission in a separate frame. For example, you might work with a two-framed page that displays the search form in the first frame and the search results in the second frame, refreshing only the results frame each time the form is submitted.

Comment: FYI: 
The target attribute was deprecated in HTML 4.01, but is back in HTML5. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#valid-browsing-context-name-or-keyword

Answer (score 2):

No target="_self" has nothing to do with it....